# Building a multi-index db

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am a python newbie. I have two lists that I need to build a MultiIndex object for.  The lists are `Letters = ['A', 'B', 'C']` and `numbers = list(range(10))`. I need to index a Series of random numbers (called S). I have compiled some code but keep getting errors. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C']
numbers = list(range(10))

def s(num, lower=0, upper=9):
    return [random.randrange(lower,upper+1) for i in range(30)]

df_test = pd.DataFrame.from_records(letters, columns=['letters'], numbers, 
df
```

As you can imagine, this is not working. If anyone can provide some suggestions I would be truly appreciative.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need for `Series` create [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) :

```
s = pd.Series(s(10),index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([letters, numbers], names=['let','num']))
print (s)
let  num
A    0      4
     1      2
     2      3
     3      8
     4      4
     5      2
     6      9
     7      9
     8      0
     9      4
B    0      0
     1      8
     2      2
     3      0
     4      0
     5      8
     6      1
     7      7
     8      7
     9      6
C    0      4
     1      2
     2      5
     3      8
     4      1
     5      4
     6      5
     7      2
     8      0
     9      2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks  - this looks great to me!